# scala pattern matching- binding single attribute in case class

Tags: scala

I have a case class with a long list of attributes e.g :

```
case class Item(itemCode: ID,
                itemType: String,
                itemName: String,
                manufacturerName: String,
                manufactureCountry: String,
                manufacturerItemDescription: String,
                unitQty: String,
                quantity: Double,
                bIsWeighted: Int,
                unitOfMeasure: String,
                qtyInPackage: Int,
                itemPrice: Double,
                unitOfMeasurePrice: Double,
                allowDiscount: Short) extends Product
```

I want to extract only a single attribute from this list using pattern matching. I can do something like :

```
{
 case Item(_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, price, _, _) => price
 case _ => 0.0
}
```

is there a more direct way to do that without writing this tedious list of placeholders ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trivial solution here is to match by type instead of using the extractor:

```
item match {
  case i: Item => i.itemPrice
  case _ => 0.0
}
```

If your case class has so many fields, this way is more conservative anyway in the sense that you are guaranteed that you won't have to patch all your patterns everytime you change the class (add/remove/reorder attributes).

It's nice to know about custom extractors, but I don't think it makes much sense here. Will you define one for each and every field?

Of course, I'm assuming that you **do** need to pattern match in the first place. In other words, this makes sense if the `item` value above does not already have the type `Item`. Otherwise this pattern matching achieves nothing more than directly do `item.itemPrice`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can add your own 'unapply' method to the Item companion object.

```
object Item {
  def unapply(item: Item): Option[Double] = Some(item.itemPrice)
}
```

[Neophyte's Guide](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html) has good info about extractors.

Then you can just use this single argument pattern matching to extract the price.

```
item match {
  case Item(price) => ???
}
```

Comment: I think you should rename your object `Item` to something like `ItemPrice`, because the _case_ class `Item` already defines an unapply method. Then you can pattern match with `case ItemPrice(price) => ...`.

Comment: Yes, Peter is right. I thought it might be allowed since this 'unapply' returns an Option[Double] whereas the default 'unapply' returns an Option[Tuple14[..]]. I guess it's an type erasure thing both methods are not allowed in same source.
On the other hand, defining the object as ItemPrice does better reflect what you're trying to accomplish and makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: @JoostdenBoer You can't have overloaded methods with the same name and argument types which differ only in return type in Scala.